# Minimal primary decomposition of extended ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $k \subset K$ be a separable field extension, $A = k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, $B=K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ and $I \leq A$ an ideal with minimal primary decomposition $$I = \mathfrak{q}_1 \cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak{q}_k.$$
Choose minimal primary decompositions 
$\mathfrak{q}_iB = \bigcap_j \mathfrak{q}_{i,j}$ in $B$.
My question:

> Is $$IB = \bigcap_{i,j} \mathfrak{q}_{i,j}$$ a minimal primary decomposition in $B$?

I know $\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}_{i,j}} \cap A = \sqrt{\mathfrak{q}_i}$, hence $\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}_{i,j}} \ne \sqrt{\mathfrak{q}_{i',j'}}$ for $(i,j) \ne(i',j')$ but how can I show, that $\cap \mathfrak{q}_{i,j} \not\subset \mathfrak{q}_{i',j'}$. Is it true, that $\mathfrak{q}_{i,j} \cap A = \mathfrak{q}_i?$

Comment: What is true is the folowing: $\bigcap_j(\mathfrak{q}_{i,j} \cap A)= \mathfrak{q}_i$.

Comment: Yes. But I still don't see how to produce a contradiction. It is clear if there are no embedded primes. I also have the feeling, that it would be wrong for non-separable field extension, but maybe this is nonsense.